Guard mind controlled to "shoot the driver"
A memory recently popped into my head of a scene from a movie or TV show where a passenger in a vehicle mind controls someone else into shooting the driver, using the exact phrase "shoot the driver." Unfortunately, that line is the only part I'm sure about, and anything else I might be imagining or conflating with other media. The other details I think I remember:

I probably watched this in the last 20 years or so, and it probably came out in that same time period.
It was live action.
The mind control was verbal, not just telepathic, and the speaker had a powerful voice (probably male).
The mind controller was a prisoner in transit, and the shooter was an armed guard. I think the guards knew about the mind control ability and had it contained somehow, but either the system failed or the guards made a mistake.
The guard does actually shoot the driver, causing the vehicle to crash and allowing the prisoner to escape.

What it's not:

Jessica Jones. The style of mind control matches, but there's no scene like this.
The Dark Knight. I might be conflating the car crash details from the scene with Dent and Maroni, but otherwise it doesn't match.


This sounds like Deadpool II -- the armored prisoner transport carrying Juggernaut -- but I don't have references to be certain.

https://www.quodb.com/search/%22shoot%20the%20driver%22?advance-search=false&keywords=%22shoot%20the%20driver%22 - I'm not seeing anything that looks an obvious match

Dune? Bene Geserit the VOICE?

I was thinking of X-Files - the "Pusher" episode, but the details don't match as well as I thought once I checked a description of the episode

My brain is going to "Push" from 2009, which has a few cases of people being commanded to kill themselves or others, but I don't see any "shoot the driver" lines in the script.

As Andrew mentions, X files S3E7 "Pusher" is similar, but the driver isn't shot...instead the mind control works by distracting the driver with the phrase "Cerulean blue" until he drives into a truck of that color (or maybe with that text).

This is Mind Games: Part 1, S1.E12 of Spider-Man: The New Animated Series (2003).
In the opening scene of the episode, the psychic Gaines Twins, Roxanne and Roland, are being transported through NYC in a prisoner transport van.
They're both connected to apparatus intravenously pumping drugs into them to keep them sedated. One guard armed with a shotgun keeps an eye on them, while another drives.



While still in motion, the van is struck from the side by another van, causing it to crash and disconnecting the twins from the drug supply. They then quickly regain consciousness and psychically compel the guard with the shotgun to shoot the driver and set them free.
The command is given psychically, not verbally, but is audible to the viewer as spoken words:

ROLAND: Shoot. Now.
ROXANNE: The driver. Shoot. Then set us free.

You can watch the full scene in the video below.




Yes! I remembered some details wrong, but the image of the uniformed guards and the shotgun absolutely clicked it for me.

It might be Dune
What matches Bene Gesserit have an ability called the Voice which acts as a form of spoken mind control.
What doesn't match, Guard didn't kill another guard with a gun, instead guards kill themselves using bladed weapons on command. And the vehicle doesn't crash.
Spoiler alert as this scene occurs at the end of the movie.

 Paul Attreides and his mother Jessica are inside of a Harkonen thopter. Jessica due to her Bene Gesserit witch powers is gagged, Paul is not. He manages to use the voice to force a Harkonen to remove his mothers gag. She then has all of the guards kill themselves.


I looked up the scene and it's a very good guess, but not the one I'm thinking of since I've never seen the movie (or any of the other adaptations).

@MJD Its worth watching.
